# How to load data on tab click in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am using the QtabWidget in Qt creator and created three tabs(tab-1,tab-2,tab-3).Each tab has around 30 fields.Now when I run the application initially the user would be on tab-1.At present all the data which is displayed in all the three tabs is pulled at once. Is there any way that when the user clicks on Tab-2 only then the data corresponding to tab-2 is loaded and the same for tab-3. I am looking for some function like "onTabClick". I checked the slots associated with the tab widget and could not find any.

Code for my form in Qt:

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

void MainWindow::onTabChanged(int tabIndex) {

    cout<<"the tab index is:"<<tabIndex<<endl;
    if (tabIndex == 0) {
        // Create the first tab elements

        cout<<"tab 0"<<endl;
    } else if (tabIndex == 1) {
        // ...

        cout<<"tab 1"<<endl;

    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    time_t now = time(0);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);

    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("First Qt Project");
    connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)));    

}



MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:


    void onTabChanged(int tabIndex);



private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QTabWidget::currentChanged(int)` signal to handle the tab changing event. I.e:

Connect signal with corresponding slot:

```
connect(tabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)));
```

and in the slot:

```
void MyClass::onTabChanged(int tabIndex) {
    if (tabIndex == 0) {
        // Create the first tab elements
    } else if (tabIndex == 1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the mainwindow.cpp file that I have in my project. I have just started using the Qt creator and I am not sure where I need to make the changes. Could you let me know how can I do it.

Comment: I was able to add the code in my file and add the slot into my mainwindow.h file also.But the function is not being called on tab change.Could you let me know what I am missing.Thanks.

Comment: @Valla, probably you missed the Q_OBJECT macro in your MainWindow class declaration. Add it, run qmake and make again. Or rebuild the project with QtCreator if you use it. Don't forget to add `connect(tabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)));` to your main window's constructor.

Comment: I updated my mainwindow.cpp file that I have now with the new code and also the mainwindow.h file where the slot for the tabwidget is added. Am I missing anything? I rebuild the project,ran qmake and then ran the project even then the function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue:

by default any slots which are created are under the section of "private slots" in the MainWindow.h file as shown below:

```
private slots:
//default slots created from the ui(when the user right clicks on a button and then connects to a     slot)
```

So in my case since the function onTabChanges is a user defined function and I manually created a SLOT for this function this should be in public slots section. So including it this way resolved the issue.

```
public slots:

void onTabChanged(int tabIndex);
```